# 2nd degree polynomial calculator's output is inconsistent

Tags: c++, visual-studio, math

The following code is supposed to read the 3 coefficients of a 2nd degree equation and output the discriminant and the solutions (if there are any) similar to this online calculator: https://calculator.tutorvista.com/math/496/2nd-degree-equation-calculator.html
But for some reason my calculator seems to get some results correctly in some cases but not most of them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    float a, b, c;

    cout << "a=" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "b=" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "c=" << endl;
    cin >> c;

    float delta = (pow(b, 2)) - (4 * a*c);
    float summit = (-b) / (2 * a);
    float x1 = (-(b) + (sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a));
    float x2 = (-(b) - (sqrt(delta)) / (2 *a));



    cout <<"Discriminant="<< delta << endl;

    if (delta < 0) {
        cout << "No solution" << endl;
    }
    else if (delta == 0) {
        cout << "Unique solution is:" << summit << endl;

    }
    else {
        cout << "First solution is:" << x1 << endl;
        cout << "Second solution is:" << x2 << endl;

    }
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Here are some rare input examples where my calculator works as intended,according to the online calculator linked above:

a=3;b=1;c=24;

a=1;b=0;c=0;

a=1;b=-4;c=4;

But things don't always go so smoothly,for example inputting 1;4;-12 gives you 8 and 0 as opposed to  6 and -2 (notice how the results are off by 2),in other cases one of the solutions would be correct while the other won't,and most of the time the reults are completely off.

I'm not exactly sure if the problem is from the discriminant or the solution,because sometimes the former would be correct while the latter isn't.

Is there a certain etiquette when it comes to writing mathematical formulas in C++ that I'm not aware of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you split up the long calculations into smaller parts, saving the results into temporary variables. Then when you step through the code line by line in the debugger (or use `std::cout <<` to print print the result) it's easier to see which calculation goes wrong.

Comment: I suggest you avoid `sqrt(delta)` until you know `delta` is positive

Comment: BTW, the expression `a * a` is often more efficient than `pow(a, 2)`.

Comment: `x^2 - 4x + 12 = 0` does not have any real roots, so 6 and -2 are definitely not them.

Comment: Some quadratic equations have complex roots (like 1;-14;12). This is why the calculation gives wrong result in these cases. Even the website you provided tells that the roots are imaginary. Where did you you get this (6,-2) solution?

Comment: Why use float when you can have double?  What about special cases?  a = 0, b = 0, c = 0?  Encapsulate this into a function and it'll be more reusable.  Locked into your main method as written, never to be used again.  What about unit tests?  There are C++ frameworks for such things.  Why aren't you using CppUnit or equivalent?

Comment: @NeilGatenby Good point,thank you.

Comment: @molbdnilo I meant 1;4;-12,my bad.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'll keep that in mind,thank you.

Comment: @duffymo I'm still an amteur so I'm still familiarizing myself with the syntaxe,but I'll start storing formula's inside methods from in the future,thank you!

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé I meant 1;4;-12,my bad.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I used to do that,but I've been trying to cut down the number of formulas in my code lately to try to keep it as simple as possible,is that not a good practice?

Comment: Not always, and the compiler is usually good at optimizing it to the very same anyway (and sometimes it can do even better). But most importantly, splitting it up helps with debugging! Once you've debugged and tested you can combine the smaller expressions into larger (like you have now), as long as your unit-testing makes sure they are still doing the same thing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Understood,thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

formula is ( -b +- sqrt(D) ) / 2a ,

but you calculate 
-b +- sqrt(D) / 2a,

because division takes precedence over addition/substruction, so your lines

```
float x1 = (-(b) + (sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a) );
float x2 = (-(b) - (sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a) );
```

should be

```
float x1 = (-(b) + sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
float x2 = (-(b) - sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
```

Comment: I thought I paid great attention to the formulas,but it works now,thank you!